# Extract nested arrays from dict using jmespath

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I have this array of dicts containing arrays out of the Ansible output of an `acme_certificate` for DNS challenges (`{{ le_challenges.results | json_query('[].challenge_data_dns') }}`):

```json
[
  {
    "_acme-challenge.foo.example.de": [
      "<token1>"
    ],
    "_acme-challenge.bar.example.de": [
      "<token2>",
      "<token3>"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_acme-challenge.baz.example.de": [
      "<token4>"
    ]
  }
]
```

As I do not need the individual `_acme-challenge` records because all domains in question are CNAME-aliased towards a single Route53-hosted zone, I need the above output to be transformed to this so that I can run a `loop` over `route53` actions:

```json
[
  "<token1>",
  "<token2>",
  "<token3>",
  "<token4>"
]
```

I tried all possible kinds of experiments including `dict2list` and `map` on the Ansible side, but I cannot find a way to accomplish this transformation since the keys containing the tokens have dynamic names. Any ideas?

Comment: => `{{ le_challenges.results | json_query('[].challenge_data_dns') | combine | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | flatten }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Querying any key of a dictionary is as simple as using a `.*` in JMESPath, you will end up with a list of list of token, then.

With that, there is a flatten operator, which is simply `[]`, you need to repeat it for every level of list you want to flatten.

This said, you will have to reset the projection you made first: with a [pipe operator](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions) — `|`.

So, your query ends up being:

```
[].challenge_data_dns.* | [][]
```

---

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: >-
      le_challenges.results | json_query(
        '[].challenge_data_dns.* | [][]'
      )
  vars:
    le_challenges:
      results:
        - challenge_data_dns:
            _acme-challenge.foo.example.de:
              - "<token1>"
            _acme-challenge.bar.example.de:
              - "<token2>"
              - "<token3>"
        - challenge_data_dns:
            _acme-challenge.baz.example.de:
              - "<token4>"
```

This yields:

```yaml
? |-
  le_challenges.results | json_query(
    '[].challenge_data_dns.* | [][]'
  )
: - <token1>
  - <token2>
  - <token3>
  - <token4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in the dictionaries *challenge_data_dns*, there might be more attributes along with *_acme-challenge.*.example.de*. Then, the expressions below do the job

```yaml
    le_tokens: "{{ le_challenges.results|
                   map(attribute='challenge_data_dns')|
                   map('dict2items')|
                   map('selectattr', 'key', 'match', key_match)|
                   map('map', attribute='value')|
                   flatten }}"
    key_match: '_acme-challenge\.(.*)\.example\.de'
```

gives

```yaml
  le_tokens:
  - <token1>
  - <token2>
  - <token3>
  - <token4>
```

---

**Notes**

Tested with the data below

```yaml
  le_challenges:
    results:
    - challenge_data_dns:
        _acme-challenge.foo.example.de:
        - <token1>
        b2: test
    - challenge_data_dns:
        _acme-challenge.bar.example.de:
        - <token2>
        - <token3>
    - challenge_data_dns:
        _acme-challenge.baz.example.de:
        - <token4>
```